# css problems w/ ie 8 and below

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I've put together this small little piece but I'm having problems with the renderings below IE9.

I've been going over a bunch of tutorials and have even tried a version of the "html shiv" technique, but to no avail.

I'm not sure what the problem is. I cross tested it and it works in pretty much every browser minus IE8 and below. I'm just curious if I'm going to have to rework an entire style sheet for the IE8 and less bunch or if I'm just missing something.

In IE8/IE7/IE6 the hover states for the buttons work, but it's as though all of the boundaries disappear.

http://www.brodieyazaki.com/matt_tiles

is a live working version.

Here's the HTML (I would include the CSS but it's long, but you can view it in developer tools sorry for the inconvenience).

```
    <section id="tile">
    <button id="toggle_button"></button>
    <section id="tile_content">
        <figure id="tile_content_figure" class="clearfix">
            <img src="imgs/tile_pic.png">
            <h1>
                &#8220;Siri's Default Settings Leave
                Your iPhone 4S Exposed&#8221;
            </h1>
        </figure>

        <div id="tile_content_link">
            <p id="from_in">
                From <a href="#">nytimes.com</a> in <a href="#">arab spring</a> 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="tile_content_comment" class="clearfix">
            <img src="imgs/user_img.png">
            <p>
                "This is the basic version of the tile"
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer id="tile_foot">
        <div id="foot_wrap" class="clearfix">
            <figure class="like_view">
                <img src="imgs/like.png">
                <span>10</span>
            </figure>
            <figure class="like_view">
                <img src="imgs/view.png">
                <span>100</span>
            </figure>
            <article id="social" class="clearfix">
                <button id="facebook"></button>
                <button id="tumblr"></button>
                <span>share</span>
            </article>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Just looking to get pointed in the right direction. I know that the CSS has features that IE8 and below won't pick up, but the head scratcher for me is that it's as though the style sheet in its entirety is broken.

please help, and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

< ie9 doesn't understand your html5 elements: article, footer, section, figure; offhand i'd just go ahead add html5.js and then turn them on in your css:

article,figure,section,footer{display:block}

i think that should fix what you are talking about

Comment: thanks albert, I added in the html5.js and it looks good, but the little toggle button doesn't show up in the IE8/IE7. Any ideas?

Comment: i see it and its functional in ie9 rolled back to compatibility view (basically ie8) but i'm on win7....are you not seeing it in native ie7 & ie8?

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of duplicate `id`'s.  `id`'s must be unique per element or a browser may ignore subsequent instances of the `id`.  You should also declare a document encoding, among other HTML Validation errors...

[http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.brodieyazaki.com/matt_tiles&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Your site is more likely to work as expected, in all browsers, when its HTML code is fully compliant.

Comment: When I did the first layout I had used Id's because they were all unique, for some reason I completely spaced out about the fact that these would eventually have multiple instances on the screen. I'm going to rework it and try it again, thank you so much for reminding me about the validator too!

Comment: It's still not rendering correctly, however it is now a valid html5 page!

Comment: @Brodie, Well, at least you don't have to worry about duplicate `id`'s being ignored.